# What is a point function?

Tags: metric-spaces

The following is a definition of a point function I came across in *Metric Spaces* by Michael O'Searcoid :

> **Definition:** Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $z \in X$. We shall call the non-negative real function $x \to d(z,x)$ defined on $X$ the point function at $z$ and denote it by $\delta_z$.

I am having trouble understanding what this definition is telling me.

What I think it is saying is that there is a function that just looks at the difference between $z$ and every value of $x \in X$.

I would appreciate it if someone could provide some clarification on this definition, and possibly provide an example.

Comment: I guess that it is like a 'new origin', so you compute the distance from $x$ to it, that is, to $z$.

Comment: Have you encountered the term "point function" and this definition in a book? What this function does is clear. But I have never heard the term.

Comment: @julien Yes I did, I forgot to include the reference. I will add it to the question now. That also explains why Google didn't have the answer.

Comment: The only thing I can think of about $\delta_z$ in such a generality is that it is $1$-Lipschitz by triangular inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

A simple example would be the real numbers with the Euclidean metric. Then let $z = 0$ and the point function sends $x \rightarrow |x|$.